# Error when using variables from different files when using threads

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have 2 functions across 2 python files. The first looks like (called file1.py)

```
import threading 
from file2 import main_task
gotime = threading.Event()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=main_task)
thread1.start()

input()
gotime.set()
```

and the second(file2.py) looks like:

```
import threading

def main_task():
    print('Waiting!')
    gotime.wait()
    print('Event has bet triggered!')
```

Now when I run it I get

```
NameError: name 'gotime' is not defined
```

So I tried to fix it by importing gotime into file2py like so:

```
from file1 import gotime
```

But then after running that, I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'main_task' from 'file2' (/my/dir/file2.py)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IISC the problem is due to circular imports, i.e. `file2.py` tries to import something from `file1.py`, but for `file1.py` to be read, it tries to import from `file2.py`. you could try to overcome the issue by e.g. passing the `gotime` variable to `main_task` as parameter like so:

`file1.py`:

```py
import threading 
from bar import main_task
gotime = threading.Event()

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=main_task, args=(gotime,))
thread1.start()

input()
gotime.set()
```

`file2.py`:

```py
def main_task(gotime):
    print('Waiting!')
    gotime.wait()
    print('Event has bet triggered!')
```

Note that I skipped the `import threading` in `file2.py` as it's not used there.